# TensorFlow cannot run with jit compile (XLA acceleration)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-xla

Platform: Windows 10
Version: TensorFlow-gpu 2.5, CUDA 11.2/11.1/11.0, cuDNN 8.1.0/8.1.1, Python 3.8
(I tried different versions of CUDA and cuDNN as listed above, each time I install a new version, I always uninstall all components of the previous version to prevent problems due to multiple versions)

When running the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.test.is_built_with_xla())
print(tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support())
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU"))
```

I get:

> True 
> True 
> [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

I am also sure it runs successfully with GPU acceleration with no problem
(in fact, I have been using this since the release of 2.5, and before this was released, I used to use 2.1, and there was no problem running).

However, when I attempt to use [XLA acceleration](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla), for example, code like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf


@tf.function(jit_compile=True)
def operation(a, b):
    return a * b


print(operation(3, 4))
```

the script fails to run with the following error message:

> ptxas returned an error during compilation of ptx to sass: 'Internal: ptxas exited with non-zero error code -1, output: '  If the error message indicates that a file could not be written, please verify that sufficient filesystem space is provided.

I am quite sure there is enough space (about 150GB left, hopefully, that is enough)

full log message below:

> 2021-08-27 13:57:51.954995: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.573366: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.604788: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0
> with properties:  pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660
> Ti computeCapability: 7.5 coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 24
> deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
> 2021-08-27 13:57:54.604957: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.612589: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.612683: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.616367: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.618204: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.623127: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.626761: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.628079: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.628215: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible
> gpu devices: 0 2021-08-27 13:57:54.628479: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild
> TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2021-08-27
> 13:57:54.628963: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0
> with properties:  pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660
> Ti computeCapability: 7.5 coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 24
> deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
> 2021-08-27 13:57:54.629231: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible
> gpu devices: 0 2021-08-27 13:57:55.124818: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device
> interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2021-08-27
> 13:57:55.124911: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
> 2021-08-27 13:57:55.124961: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
> 2021-08-27 13:57:55.125147: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created
> TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with
> 3983 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX
> 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5) 2021-08-27
> 13:57:55.174580: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:169] XLA
> service 0x15d04eef0c0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not
> guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices: 2021-08-27 13:57:55.174743:
> I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:177]   StreamExecutor
> device (0): NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
> 2021-08-27 13:57:55.254238: F
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:472] ptxas
> returned an error during compilation of ptx to sass: 'Internal: ptxas
> exited with non-zero error code -1, output: '  If the error message
> indicates that a file could not be written, please verify that
> sufficient filesystem space is provided.
>
> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: You can check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47934) GitHub issue, it has the same exit code as yours.

Comment: @DivyeshPeshavaria thanks for helping, but it is totally different issue, as I have written in my title, it is an XLA problem, it only occurs when using XLA, the issue you give is related to any training on CUDA GPU, but mine runs fine on normal training.  And plus, the issue is not solved, the author of the issue workaround by downgrading TensorFlow to early version, and failed to solve on original version

Comment: Hi @seermer,  Above Code is running fine in Colab. Please try again with a fresh environment with CUDA 11.2 and CUDNN 8.1 .Could you also  try out answer in these following   links.                                             https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40036#issuecomment-776271924                        https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/jsalkw/rtx_3090_and_tensorflow_for_windows_10_step_by/